# how to send custom fields(like fatherName) values in goto webinar api & retrieve their values in php?

Tags: php

i am using following code for passing values in array & i had already set the    fatherName at backend.How to pass value for "fatherName" & retrieve its value. i am trying to retrieve but their is an empty error of response.
Any help would be much appreciated..!!

```
<?php

$uname = "";
$pass = "";
$client_id = "";
$organizerKey = "";
$webinar_key = '';
$registrantKey = '';

$url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/$organizerKey/webinars/$webinar_key/registrants"; 

$access_token = "";

function runThis($url) {
    $access_token = "";

    $data = array("firstName"=>"test22","lastName"=>"test11","email"=>"abc@gmail.com","city"=>"abc","state"=>"abc","country"=>"xyz","phone"=>"1230","jobTitle"=>"ZX","responses"=>array(array("questionKey"=>3392655),array("answerKey"=>3392656)));
    $data_string = json_encode($data);     
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Accept: application/vnd.citrix.g2wapi-v1.1+json',
        'Content-type: application/json',
        "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=$access_token"

    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    return curl_exec($curl);

}

 $result = runThis($url);
 print_r($result);
// wrap numbers
$result = json_decode(preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+(\.\d+)?)/', '\\1:"\\2"',                    $result),true);

echo "<pre>";
echo "<hr>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending in JSON encoding you will need to retrieve RAW POST data in php using:

```
file_get_contents(“php://input”);
```

Then you can decode the JSON data as normal:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(“php://input”));
```

It is also possible to use the legacy method (but this will be depreciated in PHP 5.6):

```
$json = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

This is because, when reading the `$_POST` variable, PHP expects to receive it's native encoding `(key_1=val_1&key_2=val_2)` etc. and so will always return empty!

**Take this example:**

**send.php**

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://mypage.com';
$fields = array(
                    'lname' => 'Last,
                    'fname' => 'First'
                );

$count = count($fields)
$fields = json_encode($fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $count);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

You have just sent a POST to 'http://mypage.com' encoded as JSON.

**receive.php**

To receive the JSON encoded data you have just sent you have to read the raw post data

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(“php://input”));

var_dump($json); //do something with $json data
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: where i need to add "file_get_contents(“php://input”);"

Comment: Use it as a substitute for `$_POST`

Comment: As i am new to php. can you please help me by writing the full code.so that i should check it for my webinar.

Comment: You are sending a POST to `https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/$organizerKey/webinars/$webinar_key/registrants`, so in that page, to receive the POST data, instead of accessing `$_POST` to read the data access the way i mentioned above. Does that make more sense?

Comment: i had checked according to the help suggested by you.but i got the following error.           
file_get_contents(php:array("firstName"=>"test22","lastName"=>"test11","email"=>"dev12ad12@gmail.com","city"=>"mohali","state"=>"Alabama","country"=>"India","phone"=>"1230","jobTitle"=>"TL","responses"=>array(array("questionKey"=>3392655),array("answerKey"=>3392656)))): failed to open stream: No error in D:\xampp\htdocs\goto_webinar\getWebinar.php on line 30

Comment: i am getting an error always with this code.. but the error occurs always.Please suggest me the complete answer so that i will be able to work on it.

Comment: again i tried according to your guidelines.but i failed.Please help me.

Comment: @user2295736 Please define "Failed" did you get an error?

Comment: yeah..sure.
the error is that the data of the custom fields(such as fatherName) is not going to the webinar.